Do I need a dSYM file for a universal binary or is a dSYM for each arch enough?
I have a C++ application that compiles for x86_64, and for arm64, each compilation produces its .dSYM folder for debug symbols. I then join each binary with lipo, resulting in a universal binary.
Do I need to generate another dSYM file for this universal binary, or is a dSYM file for each arch enough?
I use this debug information with CrashPad.

dSYM for each platform is enough.
